Access azure blob from x++ to upload file through managed identity
we have utlise this link and others to upload a file from x++ to azure blob via SAS token. However, we want to achive the same via managed identity as the internal security has forbidden usage of Keys. I know that this involvs

Registering an Appid
Providing IAM access to the blob storage as data contributor/data owner role for the app id.
Generating access token in x++ based on tenantid, appid, secret, scope
utilise the access token to upload the file to azure blob.

I am unable to achieve step 4 via x++ code. Please help and also suggest any alternative OOB solution if applicable.
thanks.

Could you include more details like what scope you used to generate token and any error you faced?

thanks for your reply. I am not facing any issue while generating the access token, I need the code in c# to use the access token (which i have) and upload file to azure blob storage

the azure blob i have added the appid as 'storage blob data contributor' and the scope used to generate the token  https://storage.azure.com

Initially, I registered one application and granted Storage API permission in it as below:

Under storage account, I added "Storage Blob Data Contributor" role to above application like this:

In my case, I used below sample c# code to upload file to Azure Storage account:
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;

namespace AzureBlobUploadApp
{
    class Program
    {
        private static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string tenantId = "tenantId";
            string clientId = "appId";
            string clientSecret = "secret";
            string storageAccountName = "sridemostor1411";
            string containerName = "sri";
            string blobName = "logo.jpg";
            string filePath = "C:\\test\\logo.jpg";

            var credential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
            await UploadFileToBlobAsync(storageAccountName, containerName, blobName, filePath, credential);
        }

        private static async Task UploadFileToBlobAsync(string storageAccountName, string containerName, string blobName, string filePath, ClientSecretCredential credential)
        {
            string blobUri = $"https://{storageAccountName}.blob.core.windows.net/{containerName}/{blobName}";
            var blobClient = new BlobClient(new Uri(blobUri), credential);

            using FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath);
            await blobClient.UploadAsync(fileStream, new BlobHttpHeaders { ContentType = "application/octet-stream" });

            Console.WriteLine("File uploaded successfully!");
        }
    }
}

Response:

To confirm that, I checked the same in Azure Portal where file uploaded successfully as below:


thanks for the response. Below is how we have achieved for x++ however i will accept the .net solution which is also ans to this post considering the effort made for the reponse :)
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Client.ActiveDirectory;
using Sysem.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;

public class generateTokenViaManagedIdentity
{
    public static void main(Args _args)
    {
    //Generate azure blob token
    //Provide clientid as storage blob data contributor to the blob storage 
    str authurl = @"https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantid/";
    str clientID = "";
    str clientsecret = "";


    str accesstoken;

    ClientCredential    clientCredentials = new ClientCredential(clientid, clientsecret);
    AuthenticationContext   authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authurl, true);

    AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireToken(@"https://storage.azure.com/",clientCredentials);


    accesstoken = result.AccessToken;

  //Upload to azureblob via managedidentity authentication
   TokenCredential tokenCredential = new TokenCredential(accesstoken);

   StorageCredentials   credentials = new 
   StorageCredentials(tokenCredential);

   CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new 
   CloudStorageAccount(credentials,"AzureBlobName","core.windows.net", true);

  //below ref code for sas key
  //StorageCredentials  credentials = new 
  //StorageCredentials("AzureBlobName","SASKEY");
  //CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(credentials, true);

   CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
   CloudBlobContainer rootContainer = 
   blobClient.GetContainerReference('ContainerName')

   if(!rootContainer.Exists(null,null))
   {
      warning('azure storageparam are not set properly');
   }

   CloudBlockBlob   cloudBlockBlob = rootContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(@'filelocalpath');

   if(cloudblockblob.Exists(null,null))
   {
      info("file exists");
   }
}
}


Note that Microsoft recently deprecated the use of the WindowsAzure.Storage libraries and recommends migrating to the Azure.Storage library: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/fin-ops/get-started/removed-deprecated-features-platform-updates#migration-from-deprecated-libraries--windowsazurestorage-and-microsoftazurestorage-to-azurestorageblobs
